# When should I use setupFiles rather than setupFilesAfterEnv?

Tags: jestjs

I see that there are two config options in jest for having some code running before each tests : `setupFiles` and `setupFilesAfterEnv`. It seems to me that `setupFilesAfterEnv` gives more flexibility (I can use `jest`, `beforeEach` and so on ...), so I don't understand in what context `setupFiles` would be more useful. Can someone provide an example where you need to use `setupFiles` rather than `setupFilesAfterEnv` ?

Documentation : https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array

Answer (score 66, accepted):

We can see what different between **setupFiles** and **setupFilesAfterEnv** from the documentation.

The most important difference will probably be when it is run.

**setupFiles** will be executed

> before the test framework is installed in the environment.

**setupFilesAfterEnv** will be executed

> after the test framework has been installed in the environment.

That's why the name has AfterEnv.

I actually use both of them in my actual project.

In my case, I use the **setupFiles** to set up fro `.env` values and use the **setupFilesAfterEnv** to set up jest configuration like `jest.setTimeout(70000)`

---

**>> In my case >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>**

**jest.config.js**

```
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/tests/settings/env-setup.ts'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/testSetupFile.js'],
```

**env-setup.ts**

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

console.log(`============ env-setup Loaded ===========`);
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'tests', 'settings', '.test.env') });
```

**testSetupFile.ts**

```
// Some of the `jest` tests are very slow and cause
// timeouts on bitbucket pipeline
console.log(`============ testSetupFile Loaded ===========`);
jest.setTimeout(70000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible for you to setup those `.env` values in `setupFilesAfterEnv` ? Does it have to be setup before env is set ? Or is it just that you prefer to set them in `setupFiles` for esthetics ?

Comment: Yes, I think it's up to you. However, I think .env should be (or good) set before setupFileAfterEnv. Because usually, .env values are the most basic values for running an app. I'll edit my post to show my env-setup.ts and testSetupFile.ts

Comment: ah I see. That makes sense.

Comment: This answer makes sense, but still doesn't address the OP's question IMO.  Mechanically, yes, one runs first - but why would one put code in one vs the other?

Comment: Agree with you @killthrush : personally, I still only use `setupFilesAfterEnv`, but I got the point that some unusual setups may require `setupFiles` in some cases, if the env vars need to be set first.

Comment: Can't get over env-setup.ts and testSetupFile.js in the same example... mixing naming patterns and js/ts just for fun? XD

Comment: Don't make the rookie mistake of defining `setupFilesAfterEnv` twice and then having issues with the file not loading.